# discussing getActivityResult in class

Tags: java, android, class, android-intent, onactivityresult

There must be a way to get intent result in a class without using `onActivityResult`. By using other methods...
I dont know how, but Iam sure there is a way.

**My class that should get the result of the intent filepicker from this class without using `onActivityResult` in the `MainActivity.java` that extents activity.** `FilePicker.java`

```
package com.hadiawali.codeeditor;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class FilePicker {

  Intent filePicker = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);

  public static void startPicking(Activity activity) {
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
      Intent chooseFolder = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);
      chooseFolder.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
      activity.startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(chooseFolder, "Choose directory"), 9999);
    }
  }
}
```

**My class that extents activity.** `MainActivity.java`

```
package com.hadiawali.codeeditor;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  Button btn;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    btn = findViewById(R.id.btn);

    btn.setOnClickListener(
        new View.OnClickListener() {
          public void onClick(View v) {
            FilePicker.startPicking(MainActivity.this);
            //I need to get the intent reslut from the class without using onActivityResult
          }
        });
  }
}
```

Comment: check this out https://medium.com/droid-log/androidx-activity-result-apis-the-new-way-7cfc949a803c

Comment: The docs have a section specifically called [Receiving an activity result in a separate class](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result#separate). Did you read the documentation on Getting a result from an activity?

Answer (score 0):

**For example you send to intent from activity A to B then
in Activity A create Activity Result like below**

```
  ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> someActivityResultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(), new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {
                    if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                        // callback called 
                    }
                }
            });

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //call B activity
        someActivityResultLauncher.launch(intent);
    }
```

**in Activity B your task is successfully complete then set**

```
 setResult(RESULT_OK);
 finish();
```

**or if task is not complete successfully then put**

```
 setResult(RESULT_CANCELED);
 finish();
```